# JQuery Extension Help - Adding Conditional Statements

Tags: jquery

Im trying to write a JQuery wrapper extension that takes a content div and then shows it modally.  Im having a bit of trouble getting it to work.  It seems to work when I daisychain everything but when I try to use more than one line I break it.  The problem with daisychaining is I don't know how to get the conditionals in there.

### This doesnt work

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showAsModal = function () {
        var ret = this.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '400px', 'left': '100px', 'z-index': '9001' });
        if (this.parent('.modal-container').size() <= 0) ret = this.wrap("<div style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-container\"></div>");
        if (this.siblings('.modal-mask').size() <= 0) ret.parent().insertAfter("<div style=\"width:" + $(document).width() + "px;height:" + $(document).height() + "px;\" class=\"modal-mask\"></div>");
        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### This does

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showAsModal = function () {
        return this.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "400px", "left": "100px", "z-index": "9001" })
        .wrap("<div style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-container\"></div>")
        .parent().show()
        .append("<div style=\"width:" + $(document).width() + "px;height:" + $(document).height() + "px;\" class=\"modal-mask\"></div>")
        .end();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But I don't know how to get conditionals in there...

This is what i want to do:

### Given

```
<div id="content">
    This is a content window
</div>
```

### I want to get

```
<div class="modal-container" style="">
    <div id="content" style="position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 100px; z-index: 9001;">
        This is a content window
    </div>
    <div class="modal-mask" style="width: 1680px; height: 897px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

when I do $('#content').showAsModal();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showAsModal = function () {
    return this.each(function(){
        var self = $(this)
        self.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '400px', 'left': '100px', 'z-index': '9001'});

        if (self.parent('.modal-container').length <= 0)
            self.wrap("<div style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-container\"></div>");
        if (self.siblings('.modal-mask').length <= 0)
            self.parent().append("<div style=\"width:" + $(document).width() + "px;height:" + $(document).height() + "px;\" class=\"modal-mask\"></div>");

    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

`this.each()` will run on every element that jquery selects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to `this`, and `return ret;` returns `undefined` because `ret` is not defined. Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
var ret = this.css(...);
...
return ret;
```

Comment: That was a typo actually - The code I have there is accurate now.  this= was a desperate attempt to make it work...